Almost pythagorean triples $x^2 + y^2 = 2024 + z^2$
The question is to prove that there are infinitely many triples of natural numbers $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 2024 + z^2$.
My idea was to write $x^2 - z^2 + y^2 = 2024 \iff (x-z)(x+z) + y^2 = 2024$. Now, maybe letting $x = a+b, y=a-b$ we end up with $y^2 = 2024-4ab$. How could I elaborate from here to prove that there are infinitely many numbers?
I also noticed the fact that $2024 = 2025 - 1 = 45^2 - 1$, maybe this could also help.

Assuming your work is correct so far (I didn't check thoroughly at all), you can further reduce to $y^2/4 = (y')^2 = 506 - ab$. Now just choose values of $a$ and $b$ so that $506 - ab$ is square?

You need to prove that there are infinitely many solutions so:
$$(45^2-x^2)-(y^2-z^2)=1$$
Or:
$$(45-x) \cdot (45 + x) - (y-z)\cdot (y+z) =1$$
You take any value for $x$ (let's say $x=10$), and fill it in in the equation, so you get:
$$1925 - (y-z) \cdot (y+z) = 1$$
Or:
$$(y-z) \cdot (y+z) = 1924$$
Just write $1924$ as the product of two numbers with the same parity, like $1924 = 2 \cdot 962$, and you can easily calculate:
$$y = \frac{962 + 2}{2} = 482$$
$$z = \frac{962 - 2}{2} = 480$$
This can be done for an infinite amount of values for $x$.

Every odd integer is the diffence between two consecutive squares. For all odd $y\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough, let
$$x=-\frac12(2024-y^2+1),\quad z=-\frac12(2024-y^2+1).$$
Then,
$$x^2-z^2=(x-z)(x+z)=(2024-y^2)\cdot 1=2024-y^2$$.

ADDED:
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (2x+y+2z, x+2y+2z, 2x+2y+3z)  $$
preserves $x^2 + y^2 - z^2$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Here is a matrix
$$
A= 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
If you have a column vector
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
x  \\ 
y  \\ 
z  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
with $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = n,$  and
$$
A \cdot
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
x  \\ 
y  \\ 
z  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) =
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
u  \\ 
v  \\ 
w  \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then we also have $u^2 + v^2 - w^2 = n$
Thus we get a sequence of column vectors with $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 2024$   simply by multiplying by $A$
over and over
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
45  \\ 
0  \\ 
1  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; , \; 
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
92  \\ 
47  \\ 
93  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; , \; 
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
417  \\ 
372  \\ 
557  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; , \; 
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
2320  \\ 
2275  \\ 
3249  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; , \; 
$$
The matrix entries are positive. Starting with the second vector, the vector entries are positive integers. Also they are growing, so the vectors are distinct; so infinitely many.

Dear Professor Will Jagy, I am curious about the applications of integral positive ternary quadratic forms and would like to understand them better. I’ve also noticed that solving a problem in this area often requires a wide range of techniques, which I find fascinating.

And I'm sorry to bother more, but I believe you might have some ideas to help me solve this problem (mathoverflow.net/q/483373/478965). I hope it’s intriguing enough for you.
